# Gordon Royle's 21-vertex 21-automorphism graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-group

[OEIS A080803](https://oeis.org/A080803) lists the minimal number of vertices $a(n)$ needed to support an undirected graph whose automorphism group has order $n$. The MathWorld page on [graph automorphisms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphAutomorphism.html) links to this sequence and reproduces the list, but there is a discrepancy: MathWorld gives 23 vertices for 21 automorphisms, OEIS gives 21.

The smaller, latter value is explained by Jens Voß:

> The value $\text{A080803}(21)=21$ is due to Gordon Royle, who found a graph with 21 vertices whose automorphism group is non-Abelian of order 21 (a 2'-Hall subgroup of the group $\text{PSL}_2(7)$).

No reference is provided for this though.

> How exactly does Royle's 21-vertex 21-automorphism graph look like?

There is only one non-abelian group of order 21, $\mathbb Z_7\rtimes\mathbb Z_3$, one of whose Cayley graphs is shown below (taken from [Wedd's List](http://weddslist.com/rmdb/g.php?m=21.1)):

[image: Cayley graph of order-21 Frobenius group]

As a *directed* graph, this indeed has 21 automorphisms. However, removing the edge orientations allows reflecting the graph, raising the automorphism count to 42. So what was the graph Royle found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brute force search reveals that the smallest valency of an example is $8$. (I'm assuming the graph is vertex-transitive.)

Here is an example. Let $a$ be an element of order $3$ in the group, and $b$ and element of order $7$. Then take $S=\{a^2b^2,a^2,a^2b^3,b^4\}$ and then take the Cayley graph with respect to $S\cup S^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

The graph Royle found, which I will call the **21-21 graph** for its order and automorphism count, can be constructed via the Cayley graph approach outlined in the other answer as follows:

- The vertex set is $\{(a,b):0\le a<3,0\le b<7\}$.
- One-seventh of the edge set $E(n)$ is the union of the following three sets, where the second indices of each vertex are taken modulo 7:
  $$\{((0,n),v):v\in\{(1,n),(0,n+3),(1,n-3),(1,n-1)\}\}\\
  \{((1,n),v):v\in\{(2,n),(1,n+1),(2,n+1),(2,n-2)\}\}\\
  \{((2,n),v):v\in\{(0,n),(2,n+2),(0,n+2),(0,n+3)\}\}$$
  The entire edge set is then the union of the $E(n)$ for $0\le n<7$.

This creates an 8-regular graph with 84 edges which can split into four 21-edge circuits, one of which is a Hamiltonian cycle. The graph6 code for this graph is `TyTXPSjxOI_jfI_IoDWfIC@VoDWCxVC@S]?j`.

[image: 21-21 graph]
[image: 21-21 graph components]

SageMath code confirming that this graph has 21 automorphisms, as well as SVG sources for the above images, can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Parclytaxel/505aa8c2d1bcde9c308acef2e4f0cd36).

Comment: Very nice pictures! I'd just like to add that there are other examples, of larger valency. (For example, one can obviously take complements.) I also didn't check if all the ones of valency 8 were isomorphic. So it might be more correct to say this is one of the graphs Royle found. (He probably found them all, as this is an easy brute-force search.)

Comment: I just checked, up to isomorphism, there is one of valency 8, one of valency 12 (its complement), and two of valency 10 (which are complements of each other).

Comment: By the way, since you seem to be familiar with graph6. If you want to do it yourself next time, Gordon puts a lot of his stuff online at http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00013890/ (Or at least, he used to.)
So you can go to http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00013890/remote/cayley/index.html
Then find the group you want, and he has precomputed all the graphs, up to isomorphism, and you can download them in graph6 format. (There are just 33 for this group.)